# How to drop all frames without a certain color in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a `mp4` video file and I want to remove all frames, that do not have a certain color.

I know about the `colorhold` filter, which turns everything grey except the specified color. But then I would need to remove every grey frame and I could not find a way to do that.

Comment: I think that you will have to extract all the frames and get them back together... don't think that there is a way to do it natively.

Comment: @FlashThunder Okay, and how would I do that?

Comment: Maybe with `mpdecimate` https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate

Comment: I agree with @FlashThunder. While FFmpeg has a vast collection of filters, none that I'm aware of crosses time and space. In your case, frame selection (temporal) and color detection (spatial). If Python is an option, I can show how to do so fairly compactly.

Comment: Ohh, misconception on my side. My plan was to use `colorhold`, but turn the frame black, not grey, and then use `blackdetect`, which decides to either write the frame to the output file or not. Turns out: I didn't understand `blackdetect` correctly. Apparently it just points out when black frame sections start and end. But 30 lines of Python and OpenCV did the trick.